# How to test AsyncTask triggered by a click?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onclick, onclicklistener, android-testing

If the `AsyncTask` is triggered by a click event on a button, how can I test it - how can I wait until the AsyncTask completes?

Note I can always execute the `AsyncTask` directly in my test method, I know how to test such scenario. However, if I insist on on using simulating the `onClick` event using `performClick()` can I still test my registration process?

**MainActivityFunctionalTest**

```
public class MainActivityFunctionalTest extends
            ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    // ...
        public void testRegistration() {
        ImageButton submitBtn = (ImageButton) solo.getView(R.id.BtnR);
        assertNotNull(submitBtn);


        submitBtn.performClick();
                // How to do something when the registration is done?
        }
    // ...
    }
```

**MainActivity** (of the project to be tested)

```
ImageButton submitBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.BtnRegister);
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRegistration();
            }
        });

public void sendRegistration() {
        Processor processor = new Processor();// subclass of AsyncTask
        processor.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do :

```
myAsyn obj = new myAsyn();
obj.execute();

while(obj.getStatus()==AsynTask.status.Finished)
{
//wait here
}

//when it finishes , this code will going to execute.
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems like an alternative to `CountDownLatch`. My challenge is to test the `AsyncTask` which is indirectly triggered throught the `onClick` event. You are all basically telling me to execute the `AsyncTask` within my test class - bypassing the `onClick` event of the button

Comment: you can create object of asyn in oncreate then on your onclick method execute that asyntask and call a method name like 'waitForMe' which contain the definition of this while loop which waits until asyn finish.

Comment: I believe there's a huge misunderstanding here. Kindly checkout my edit :)

Comment: hmm...i didn't get your edits..:P..but i think you can use here broadcast receiver so when your work of registration finishes, send broadcast that registration process finishes..then you can perform what you want to do after registration.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use get() method to wait until task complete.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Use your `Activity` from your `ActivityTestCase`. Find the view by id and simply send the event to your view.

More info on [runTestOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#runTestOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
private void buttonTest(Activity activity, int buttonId){
   Button button = (Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
    assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", button);
    button.performClick();
}

private void runButtonTest(Activity activity, int buttonId){
       getInstrumentation().runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                buttonTest(activity,buttonId);
            }
     Object o = activity.mAsyncTask.get();
     assertNotNull(o);
}
```

Alternatively you can wait until `Status` of the `AsyncTask` changes to `Status.Finished`.

Comment: get methods return result from doInbackground But if we see the lifecycle of asyntask onpostExecute still left to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of the asynctask using that you can perform your operations for more details check the link below

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html