# Android, converting an AsyncTask into a public void function?

Tags: android, asynchronous

In my android code I have an `AsyncTask` which seems to be impossible to convert to a simple `Public void` function.

```
 private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));
        //  WeatherC = params[0];
        try {
            weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

            // Let's retrieve the icon
            weather.iconData = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weather;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
        super.onPostExecute(weather);

        if (weather.iconData != null && weather.iconData.length > 0) {
            // Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(weather.iconData, 0, weather.iconData.length);
            //imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
        }
        WeatcherCels = ("" + Math.round((weather.temperature.getTemp() - 273.15)) + " C");

        Toast.makeText(context, WeatcherCels, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

The way that I execute the `task` is by:

```
 JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{"canada,toronto"});
```

However I'm trying to use simply something like:

```
String WeatherStr = getWeather("canada,toronto");
```

Comment: Why you want to change it ? If you are doing some background task like downloading data from internet in your Asynctask then don't change it to simple function. Otherwise it will show `MainThread exception` in higher version devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do :

create method like this :

```
 String getWeather(String... arr)
{
    JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
    task.execute(arr);
    return task.get();
}
```

and then

```
String weather = getWeather("a","b");
```

but it will block the ui until asyntask doinbackground finished.

Comment: I just don't want my app to to it in the background... isn't this the same thing as JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
    task.execute(arr); ??

Comment: since you are making a network request you have to use either a thread or asyntask.

Comment: There's a problem with     return task.get();

Comment: what..post that here.

Comment: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Adding try/catch didn't even help

Comment: it will not help because the execution time is greter than ui wait time.

Comment: that's why it is throwing exception.

Comment: Do you know how I can know from outside the AsyncTask when the task is complete?

Comment: yes..you can check for task status using task.getStatus and compared with Asyntask.Status.FINISHED....i have alrady answer this. wait i post the link too.

Comment: see here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692974/how-to-test-asynctask-triggered-by-a-click/21693032#21693032

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem appropriate since it causes the app to crash most the times.